# method "pod_health_probe_method_ignore_errors" not found while finding out if l3-agent alive in openstack-helm

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-neutron

The error log is below:

```
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server [-] Exception during message handling: oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher.NoSuchMethod: Endpoint does not support RPC method pod_health_probe_method_ignore_errors
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 166, in _process_incoming
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/openstack/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 274, in dispatch
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     raise NoSuchMethod(method)
2020-09-04 07:44:08.096 50 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher.NoSuchMethod: Endpoint does not support RPC method pod_health_probe_method_ignore_errors
```

While this is technically working correctly, the exceptions pollute the log files and make it harder for user to see possible real errors.
It's unlikely to nove, neutron doesn't have a basic mothed like 'ping', is there any proper way to let this except sliently?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newer to the openstack-helm. I checked the history, the "ERROR" seems work as designed.

> Neutron DHCP/L3/OVS agents:
> Sends an RPC call with a non-existence method to agent’s queue.
> Assumes no other agent subscribed to tunnel-update queue other
> than OVS. Probe is success if agent returns with NoSuchMethod
> error.

https://github.com/openstack/openstack-helm/commit/da508727b6610e3b3c89077c7a9aa05a0b7a5ea0

Answer (score -1):

The meeting has answered the question before.
Neutron needs a response,so they use the nonsense `pod_health_probe_method_ignore_errors` mthod to ilicit a response .

[Thursday, 2019-10-30](https://meetings.opendev.org/irclogs/%23openstack-helm/%23openstack-helm.2019-10-30.log.html)

[Thursday, 2019-10-31](https://meetings.opendev.org/irclogs/%23openstack-helm/%23openstack-helm.2019-10-31.log.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).